# Domplate for JSON Firebug extension

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, tags, firebug

I am creating a firebug extension. I need to display json in the panel, I am using textarea to display panel but it doesn't work, extension simply crashes.
I tried this:

```
var template = domplate(
        { 

                tag:
                TEXTAREA({"class": "textEditorInner", type: "text"},json)
        });
```

but the plugin crashes, it works for normal text however.

Comment: Odd. Is that the only code you have in your extension?

Comment: @fflorent obviously not. Anyways I fully tested domplate and it does not support displaying json in input or textarea due to double quotes, so I used ACE editor instead.

Comment: Ask your question in the Firebug forum here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebug. People of Firebug will definitely help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your `json` variable should contain a string with backslash escaped quotes when passing it to the template.

Other solution would be to first render your template

```
var textarea = template.render();
```

and then add the content afterwards via

```
textarea.value = json;
```

Of course you'll then need to remove the `json` from your template.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already used ACE lib instead of domplate.